# What does "parmi" mean?

Tags: translation

In a lot of Italian operas, I frequently hear the word "parmi". Either used in the middle of a sentence, or in the beginning of the final cabaletta in *L'Assedio di Corinto*.

Yet, no translation service or dictionary I've checked has this word. I've studied Italian for a year, so in the aria's name *Parmi vederlo*, I know that *vederlo* is *see it*. So my thought is it might be Pare+mi, as an imperative case, but *pare* is not the infinitive of any verb I can find. And even if you use *parere* the context doesn't make sense, since the sentence would seem to read like "It seems to see it...".

For context, the full sentence is, "Parmi vederlo, ahi misero vicino a morte orribile."

Any help with this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your analysis is correct. The word *parmi* is indeed a contraction of *mi pare*, where *pare* is the third person of *parere*. So *parmi* means “it seems to me”, or “it appears to me”.

In your example, *parmi vederlo* simply means (in a non-idiomatic English) “it seems to me that I see him”, in the sense of “it's almost as if I could see him”.

Probably your confusion comes from the fact that in these sentences *parere* is constructed impersonally, so *parmi* = *mi pare* = “it seems to me that I...” (and not “It seems to see it...”).

(As for *vederlo*, it could be both “to see him” and “to see it”; Italian has no neuter gender. From the context, here it refers to a “him”.)

Comment: Thanks for that detailed breakdown! So would the full sentence be something like: "It seems to me that I see it, ah they were put close to a horrible death."? It seems like an odd sentence, but I know that operatic/poetic Italian is not necessarily proper.

Comment: @Marco: Not quite: “It seems to me that I see him, ah the wretched man, close to a horrible death”. Here *misero* is [this adjective](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/misero/), not a form of the verb *mettere*.

Comment: Interesting. I have to go back to the text because I don't remember there being any man in the scene (just her with a group of ladies). But I'll defer to you.

Comment: @Marco: I don't know this particular opera, but it would seem from this sentence that the unhappy chap she talks about is not present but elsewhere (prison? battlefield?) and she “sees” him with her mind's eye.

Comment: I'd say `It's as if I saw him [now]`, rather than the literal `It seems I see him`. But I'm not italian.

Comment: Indeed, @entonio: in my answer I paraphrase it as “it's almost as if I could see him”.